# Connecting to a gcloud vm instance via ssh

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, bitnami

### Problem:

I cannot connect via ssh to my vm instance on gcloud

### Description:

I am using gcloud with my own domain as the user userid@mydomain.com

1. I created a vm instance on Google Cloud Engine
2. I installed "WordPress Multisite Certified by Bitnami" via Cloud Launcher

The vm is up and running, I can even access a wordpress page.
In the section "VM Instances", I click the button SSH, but cannot connect, the window prompts:

> Transferring SSH keys to the VM.
>
> Could not connect, retrying (1/3)...

The log does not contain any errors.

**Attempt 1: Gcloud API**

In the Windows CMD, I can successfully connect by calling

```
gcloud compute ssh userid_mydomain_com@MY_INSTANCE_NAME
```

It generates file in C:\Users\ACCOUNT_NAME.ssh, but the file google_compute_engine.pub contains my Windows account name at the end in the format HOST\account_name@host, not my gcloud user name (userid@mydomain.com)!

I retried the ssh button, but it still failed.
I then pasted the content from the file google_compute_engine.pub into the ssh key field, but it still doesnt work, perhaps due to the wrong user name? I changed the name, but that didnt help.

**Attempt 2: PuttyGen**

I also tried generating ssh key with PuttyGen as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#createsshkeys) and used userid@mydomain.com in the key comment. With or without the newly generated public key in the vm instance configuraton, I can not ssh into the vm.

### Question:

How can I access my vm on gcloud via the ssh button and via putty?

### Update:

I can connect to my vm instance using Putty and WinSCP.
I entered the keyfile provided in the Bitnami launchpad and the user name 'bitnami'. The ssh buttons, however, still dont make me enter.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be using the right credentials. However, it's pretty weird the Web Browser Terminal Google offers 
 you through the **SSH** button doesn't work.

Please take a look to the documentation below and try to follow the steps, it might help you: 
https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/#how-to-connect-to-the-server-through-ssh

Comment: I followed your guide but experienced the same. I even started a new Bitnami app via the Bitnami launchpad completely from scratch, clicked "Lauch ssh console" and again it read "Could not connect, retrying (1/3)..." (both in the gcloud console and the Bitnami launchpad)

Comment: Could you try to connect to the server using a SSH Client (not using the browser). You can use Putty or an SSH Client via terminal:
https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/#connecting-with-an-ssh-client

In order to obtain your SSH Credentials, visit this link:
https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/#obtaining-your-ssh-credentials-for-your-client?

Comment: Yes, as described above, I can connect using Putty and WinSCP, but not through any of the ssh buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to a VM instance via many ways:

1. SSH from Google cloud console
2. Connect via Cloud shell
3. Connect via your local terminal with gcloud command with IAP by using --tunnel-through-iap parameter.

gcloud compute ssh userid_mydomain_com@MY_INSTANCE_NAME --tunnel-through-iap